# Why can't rails3 find ApplicationController when it is in my application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, applicationcontroller

In a Rails3 Application I keep getting

`..gems/activesupport-3.0.0.beta/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:459:in 'load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant ApplicationController (NameError)`

Even though `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` exists and is valid. What is the problem

Answer (score 0):

There are probably several causes of this, but the one that got me was having a `config.ru` file in my home directory:

Rails3 attempts to figure out where your application's root directory is. The logic for this is begin looking in the directory `../railties/lib/rails/application`, and then walking up the path looking for a directory with `config.ru` and assuming that is the app root - if none is found then the current working directory is the app root.

If your Gems are installed in a subdirectory of your home dir (RVM, Local Gems and Bundler do this) then at one point this will check for the existence of `config.ru` in your home dir. If this exists it will try to load the application from your home dir.

The solution is to not have `config.ru` in your home dir

Comment: Another solution would be to have a valid config.ru file that booted your Rails application in the application's root.